# how to reconfigure gitignore_global.txt

Tags: git, gitignore, git-config

Due to a companywide account migration I do see an error while doing a git action like `git checkout my/branch`: `'\\old\now\nonexistent\path\to\my\home\documents\\gitignore_global.txt': Permission denied`

I would like to reconfigure git, where can I do this? I don't see any local configuration pointing to this directory..

Answer (score 2):

To set the path to your global exclude file (or to set any other global option for that matter) use something like:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile "%USERPROFILE%\.gitignore"
```

*(assuming you are on a Windows machine)*

Also see [Customizing Git - Git Configuration](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).